# Devolver cualquier Json en un endpoint

Tags: json, webservice, rest, google-app-engine, endpoint

Tengo un endpoint en gae, pero necesito poder devolver un String que contenga un json, sin crear un POJO, pero no he encontrado una forma de hacerlo, este es uno de mis endpoinds :

```
    @ApiMethod(name = "get", httpMethod = "POST", path = "/get")
public String get() {

        return "{"defenseCards": "fsdfsd","friends": 5,"previousRank": 0}";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Devolver String o arrays no esta soportado. [Según la documentación](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/parameter-and-return-types#the_response_object) el endpoint deberia devolver un POJO o un CollectionResponse